# Cannot use group by and over(partition by) in the same query?

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, partition-by

I have a table `myTable` with 3 columns. `col_1` is an `INTEGER` and the other 2 columns are `DOUBLE`. For example, `col_1={1, 2}, col_2={0.1, 0.2, 0.3}`. Each element in `col_1` is composed of all the values of `col_2` and `col_2` has repeated values for each element in `col_1`. The 3rd column can have any value as shown below:

```
    col_1 | col_2 | Value
    ----------------------
    1     |  0.1  |  1.0
    1     |  0.2  |  2.0
    1     |  0.2  |  3.0
    1     |  0.3  |  4.0
    1     |  0.3  |  5.0
    2     |  0.1  |  6.0
    2     |  0.1  |  7.0
    2     |  0.1  |  8.0
    2     |  0.2  |  9.0
    2     |  0.3  |  10.0
```

What I want is to use an aggregate-function `SUM()` on the `Value` column partition by `col_1` and grouped by `col_2`. The Above table should look like this:

```
    col_1 | col_2 | sum_value
    ----------------------
    1     |  0.1  |  1.0
    1     |  0.2  |  5.0
    1     |  0.3  |  9.0
    2     |  0.1  |  21.0
    2     |  0.2  |  9.0
    2     |  0.3  |  10.0
```

I tried the following SQL query:

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, sum(Value) over(partition by col_1) as sum_value
from myTable
GROUP BY col_1, col_2
```

But on DB2 v10.5 it gave the following error:

```
SQL0119N  An expression starting with "Value" specified in a SELECT 
clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER BY clause is not specified in the 
GROUP BY clause or it is in a SELECT clause, HAVING clause, or ORDER 
BY clause with a column function and no GROUP BY clause is specified.
```

Can you kindly point out what is wrong. I do not have much experience with SQL.

Thank you.

Comment: What has MySQL to do with the question? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution.

I do not need to use `OVER(PARTITION BY col_1)` because it is already in the `GROUP BY` clause. Thus, the following query gives me the right answer:

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, sum(Value) as sum_value
from myTable GROUP BY col_1, col_2
```

since I am already grouping w.r.t `col_1` and `col_2`.

Dave, thanks, I got the idea from your post.

Answer (score 29):

Yes, you can, but you should be consistent regarding the grouping levels. 
That is, if your query is a GROUP BY query, then in an analytic function 
you can only use "detail" columns from the "non-analytic" part of your selected 
columns. 
Thus, you can use either the GROUP BY columns or the non-analytic aggregates, 
like this example:

```
select product_id, company, 
sum(members) as No_of_Members, 
sum(sum(members)) over(partition by company) as TotalMembership 
From Product_Membership 
Group by Product_ID, Company
```

Hope that helps

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, sum(Value) over(partition by col_1) as sum_value
    -- also try changing "col_1" to "col_2" in OVER
from myTable
GROUP BY col_2,col_1
```

Comment: I already saw that example. I can do it that way but then I get the total sum for each element in `col_1` instead of the sum for each distinct element in `col_2` per elements in `col_1`

Comment: I had this same problem, and Dave, your query gave me exactly what I needed.

Comment: hi, nice example. Does that mean the partitioned column need to be a subset of the grouped by columns?  And what does the `sum(sum(` mean?

Comment: Hi @dave, I am curious what you mean by detail" columns ; non-analytic" part of your selected columns; can you please maybe specify the column names ? Or give examples which one should not do?

Comment: Another curious Q: is group by applied first or partition by applied first, when they are used together.