# SUM OVER PARTITION and GROUP BY in one pass?

Tags: sql, sum

My question is similar to this but the answer is not what I want:

[Cannot use group by and over(partition by) in the same query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250503/cannot-use-group-by-and-overpartition-by-in-the-same-query#)

My table is like this:

```
CODE_1  CODE_2  AMOUNT
A       A.1     2
A               4
A               6
B               1
B       B.1     3
B       B.1     5
```

I want to get the total of Code_1 and [Code_1, Code_2] like this:

```
CODE_1  CODE_2  Total_1 Total_2
A       A1      12      2
B       B1      9       8
```

Can I get the result in one SELECT? Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using? DB2? Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Use a derived table or CTE. Do the grouping in the inner table.

Comment: Can there be different `CODE_2` values for a given `CODE_1`?  If so, what should that look like in your output?

Comment: Since we only have NULL and one value in Code_2 column for a given Code_1, I almost forgot this condition. But there maybe more values in Code_2 in the future. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for? It's hard to know how you intend to treat the `CODE_2` data:

```
select
    code_1, 
    max(CODE_2) as CODE_2,
    sum(AMOUNT) as Total_1,
    sum(case when CODE_2 is not null then AMOUNT end) as Total_2
from T
    group by CODE_1
```