# How to sum from multiple columns and segregate into separate column if result is positive and negative

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am using postgresql and need to write a query to sum values from separate columns of two different tables and then segregate into separate columns if positive or negative.

For Example,

Below is the source table

[image]

Below is the resultant table which need to be created also used while populating it

[image]

I have written below query to aggregate sum and able to populate TOT_CREDIT and TOT_DEBIT column. Is there any optimized query to achieve that ?

```
select  t.account_id,
        t.transaction_date,
        SUM(t.transaction_amt) filter (where t.transaction_amt >= 0) as tot_debit,
        SUM(t.transaction_amt) filter (where t.transaction_amt < 0) as tot_credit,
        case
        when
        (
            SUM(t.transaction_amt) + 
            SUM(COALESCE(b.credit_balance,0)) +
            SUM(COALESCE(b.debit_balance,0))
        ) < 0
        then
        (
            SUM(t.transaction_amt) + 
            SUM(COALESCE(b.credit_balance,0)) +
            SUM(COALESCE(b.debit_balance,0))
        )
        end as credit_balance,
        case
        when
        (
            SUM(t.transaction_amt) + 
            SUM(COALESCE(b.credit_balance,0)) +
            SUM(COALESCE(b.debit_balance,0))
        ) > 0
        then
        (
            SUM(t.transaction_amt) + 
            SUM(COALESCE(b.credit_balance,0)) +
            SUM(COALESCE(b.debit_balance,0))
        )
        end as debit_balance,
from 
    transaction t   

LEFT OUTER JOIN balance b ON (t.account_id = b.account_id 
                                        and t.transaction_date = b.transaction_date 
                                        and b.transaction_date=t.transaction_date- INTERVAL '1 DAYS')
group by
    t.account_id,
    t.transaction_date
```

Please provide some pointer.

**EDIT 1: This query is not working in expected manner.**

Answer (score 0):

One way is to break your logic into smal queries and join them in the end!

```
select tw.account_id, tw.t_date,tw.t_c,th.T_D,fo.C_B,fi.d_B from 
(select account_id, Transaction_date as t_date, sum(Transaction_AMT) as t_C from TransactionTABLE 
where Transaction_AMT<0 group by  account_id, Transaction_date ) as tw inner join
(select account_id, Transaction_date as t_date, sum(Transaction_AMT) as t_d from TransactionTABLE 
where Transaction_AMT>0 group by  account_id, Transaction_date ) as th on tw.account_id=th.account_id and tw.t_date=th.t_date inner join
(select account_id, Transaction_date as t_date, sum(Transaction_AMT) as C_B from TransactionTABLE 
where sum(Transaction_AMT)<0 group by  account_id, Transaction_date ) as fo on th.account_id=fo.account_id and th.t_date=fo.t_date inner join
(select account_id, Transaction_date as t_date, sum(Transaction_AMT) as d_B from TransactionTABLE 
where sum(Transaction_AMT)>0 group by  account_id, Transaction_date ) as fi on fi.account_id=fo.account_id and fi.t_date=fo.t_date;
```

Or else

You could try something as follows which calculates the running count of d_B over the Transaction_date and account_id

```
select  account_id,
        transaction_date,
        SUM(transaction_amt) filter (where transaction_amt >= 0) as tot_debit,
        SUM(transaction_amt) filter (where transaction_amt < 0) as tot_credit,
sum(transaction_amt) over (partition by account_id where sum(transaction_amt)<0) as credit_balance,
sum(transaction_amt) over (partition by account_id where sum(transaction_amt)>=0) as debit_balance
from TransactionTABLE group by account_id, Transaction_date order by 1,2;
```

Comment: I have editted my question and provided working query , just wanted to know which way is better

Comment: Maybe, you can check it by yourself by testing the complexity and execution time of both the queries and then you have your answer!!

Comment: My query is not working in expected way. Is there any way by which I can have less joins as shown in your query to achieve performance benefit

Comment: You could use over partition method to calculate such running counts in your scenario. I'm not sure whether, I have used them properly, why don't you give it a try? More on this can be found at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29250503/cannot-use-group-by-and-overpartition-by-in-the-same-query)